# how to use poller in int-ftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

first,thanks for your attention
i defined a outbound-gateway ftp adapter with polling as bellow code :

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                              session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                              request-channel="inboundFileChannel"
                              command="ls"
                              command-options="-1"
                              expression="'books/*'"
                              reply-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
```

but I got the following exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 57; columnNumber: 40; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'int:poller'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp":request-handler-advice-chain}' is expected.
what is correct action for above problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [fixed in version 4.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3462). The current version is 4.1.3.

If you can't move to 4.1.x (recommended), you can add a `<bridge/>` to bridge the pollable channel to a direct channel.

Comment: thanks for fast reply gary,it's worked, but return empty list and show bellow   message :
DEBUG PollingConsumer:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'

Comment: An empty list means that no files were found matching the requested pattern. 'Received no message...` simply means there are no messages in `inboundFileChannel`.

Comment: thanks @Gary Russell for reply, i'm sure the root ftp directory contain many files and directories , i changed _`command-options`_ attr to  `-dirs` and the channel as bellow  
`<int:channel id="output">  
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="inboundGet">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>`
but not fixed :(

Comment: If you are getting an empty list then there are no files matching `books/*`.

Comment: yes  that's right, but i change _`expression`_ attr to `payload`
the adapter code is:

Comment: i see the ftp server log , and Not send any request for it.

Comment: `payload` simply means the message payload contains the path for the `ls` search. I suggest you look at a network monitor such as wireshark to see the interactions with your server.

Comment: i change log level to TRACE and see
_`TRACE QueueChannel:426 - postReceive on channel 'inbound1', message is null`_ message log, what is you idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75637/discussion-between-alireza-ala-and-gary-russell).